# Rails 3.2 + Ruby 1.9 + block variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, block, instance

What's standard practice for Rails now? Before Ruby 1.9 I could do this...

```
<% @records.each do |@record| %>
  <%= form_tag "/do/something" do %>
    <%= text_field 'record', 'text' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= a_display_record_helper %>
  <%= render :partial => "record_partial" %>
<% end %>
```

But now we can't use instance variables in blocks. So what are standard practices for blocks containing forms, view helpers and partials?

Comment: `But now we can't use instance variables in blocks` - what? What error do you get?

Comment: In Ruby 1.9 you get a "formal argument cannot be an instance variable"

Answer (score 1):

In `ruby 1.9` the block variable name cannot start with `@`:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <%= form_tag "/do/something" do %>
    <%= text_field 'record', 'text' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= a_display_record_helper %>
  <%= render :partial => "record_partial" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's not a typo. This is valid syntax for Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Yes, I know you can't. That's not my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can still pass the record variable to the helper as a parameter and for the partial too. It is easier to understand what is going on if you do that, anyway.

Comment: Yes. I'm just wondering what is standard practice for forms, helpers and partials.

Comment: I think it is what I wrote.